# Is there any efficient algorithm to compute the intersection of two polytopes?

Tags: convex-analysis, computational-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ being two polytopes defined by their vertices.

I there any efficient way to compute $P_3 = P_1 \cap P_2$?

It seems the intersection of the polytopes can be represented as the union of the two inequalities system. How to implement it?

Comment: Just the vertices isn't enough to determine the polytope, unless you also know that it's convex. If it's convex you should start by finding the convex hull, which will tell you the topology of the polytope: which vertices share edges, which cycles of edges form faces, etc.

Comment: And what if P1 and P2 can be defined using H-representation?

Comment: I'd suggest you start by just considering the problem i  two dimensions. Doing this will probably make many issues clearer for you.

Comment: That is what I am doing but it still remains unclear to me. Moreover, I need to translate this in R, so I really need to get to the bottom of this and understand what is possible in therms of algorithm, or not.

Comment: If $P_1 = \{x\in\mathbb R^n : Ax\leqslant b\}$ and $P_2 = \{x\in\mathbb R^n: A'x\leqslant b'\}$, then it seems reasonable that $$P_1\cap P_2 = \{x\in\mathbb R^n: Ax\leqslant b, A'x\leqslant b'\}, $$ as you stated. However, if all we know are the vertices of the polytopes, then I have no clue of an algorithm to determine the intersection.

Comment: I have read that it should be possible to do it using linear programming. Do you have any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Speaking of the linear programming, the simplex method may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I found that, from my set of points, I create inequalities by using the vertices as the coefficients of every equation that is <=1. Then I enumerate the vertices of the convex set created by those vertices. If I can find the equation of the lines that wrap those vertices, their coefficients equal the intersection of the original polyhedra. Do you know how to find those equations?

Comment: You should google for "translating between $\mathcal V$- and $\mathcal H$-representations of polytopes" or something like that. If I remember correctly, there is also an initial section in Ziegler's "Lectures on Polytopes" about this (if not, then there will be at least a reference). Convert your polytope in $\mathcal H$-representation, intersect these as described by Math1000, and convert the intersection back to $\mathcal V$-representation (if you need to). I know of no better way. Also, translating between these representations can be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that one defines a convex polytope as the convex hull of a finite number of vertices the so called $H$-representation in the comment section can also be a representation of the polytope by means of the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** A non-empty set P of Rn is a (convex) polytope if, and only if, it is a bounded polyhedral set.

Since a bounded polyhedral is already defined as the **intersection** of halfspaces and the intersection of bounded sets is again bounded you might do just as it was stated in the comments:

$$P_1 \cap P_2 = \{x\in\mathbb R^n: Ax\leqslant b, A'x\leqslant b'\},$$

This problem does not characterizes itself as an LP but there are different problems that use the new polytope $P$ that can be stated in the form of an LP. An example can be finding the smallest distance between a given point outside the polytope and the polytope.

If I may suggest, this program [PORTA](http://porta.zib.de/) is easy to download and run. It will be suitable for you to change between H and V representations. If, after you characterize the polytope you would like to ask LP questions I suggest [linprog](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) in MatLab.